# Duplicate arrays on complex join

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to create denormalized view of a complex structure in my postgresql db. I have a main entity `games`, and a few one-to-many relations, such as `tags` (two types) and `files`. The problem is arrays containes items with duplicate ids regardless of `distinct` clause inside subqueries. I'll narrow query to the related part:

```
select
  array_to_json(array_remove(array_agg((
    select distinct t.id where t.type = 1
  )), null))::jsonb as genre_ids
from games g
left outer join game_tags gt on gt.game_id = g.id -- one-to-many
left outer join tags t on gt.tag_id = t.id
left outer join game_files gf on gf.game_id = g.id -- one-to-many as well
left outer join files f on gf.file_id = f.id
left outer join ratings r on r.game_id = g.id
group by g.id;
```

Let's say I have game with `id=1` and relations

```
# game_tags (game_id, tag_id)
1, 100

# game_files (game_id, file_id)
1, 1000
1, 1001
1, 1002
1, 1003
```

Then in query result I'll see array `[100, 100, 100, 100]`. The same situation when tags amount is greater than one. I don't know if this because of wrong aggregating section or because of wrong grouping. I hoped that `distinct` keyword will do the trick, but it don't. Of course I can filter items before sending it to the frontend, but I believe this is a wrong way.

I sticked to pg 9.5.

Comment: No, `tags` is just list of tags, while `game_tags` is a relation. I just simplified the query, I need files as well, its aggregation looks pretty the same. In select distinct clause I need to filter only tags wihth type=1 and type is stored in `tags` table. Maybe I doing something conceptionally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you need to group on different bases: once for the game tags and once for the files. You can solve this by sub-queries as row sources. The grouping takes place in the sub-queries so they do not influence each other:

```
select g.*, t.genre_ids, f.file_ids
from games g
left join (
  select gt.game_id, jsonb_agg(t.id) as genre_ids
  from game_tags gt
  join tags t on gt.tag_id = t.id
  where t."type" = 1
  group by gt.game_id) t on t.game_id = g.id
left join (
  select game_id, jsonb_agg(file_id) as file_ids
  from game_files
  group by game_id) f on f.game_id = g.id
left join ratings r on r.game_id = g.id -- not used
;
```

Comment: Thank you. Works exactly as I expected. Too bad I didn't realize it on my own.

Comment: SO exists so that we can learn from each other. I know that I have learned a good deal of excellent coding techniques here, just by browsing around. Good luck with your future coding.